# Get selected RadioButton inside a group

Tags: c#, winforms, radio-button

I have a winforms app with a group box called **priceClassGroupBox**. Inside it I dynamically add RadioButtons to which I give a *name*, say **radio1**, **radio2**, **radio3**.

I have 2 questions:

1. Can I automatically select a given RadioButton by it's *name* without iterating through each control?
2. Can I get the *name* of the selected RadioButton without iterating through each control?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes you can call [Controls.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28VS.80%29.aspx)

eg

`RadioButton rdo = (RadioButton)priceClassGroupBox.Controls.Find("radio1", false);`

2 . No you would have to iterate through and find the selected radio button